# how to run github project of react native

Tags: react-native

I'm getting an error while I'm doing `react-native run-android`

```
error: 
Command `start` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.
```

Comment: Are you running the command inside your root project folder ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your root directory where package.json is placed along with other directories like android/ios, run the command `npm install`. Then run 
`react-native link` (not compulsorily required, required in case there are third party libraries to be linked). Then run `react-native run-android` (supposing you don't have sdk path problem and you have an emulator running).

This is the most common way of starting a git project. Let me know if you face other problems.

Comment: i did the same but after it i am getting new error Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Comment: Can you share the github link if you are trying with some public repo?